# How to make last row behave as normal till it reach the end of viewport and then act as floating row in AgGrid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a total row in my grid. I want this row to append to the last row, if the number of rows are less and not filling the complete viewport. If the grid body height exceeds viewport height, the total row should act as a floating row. How to do that in AgGrid?

Thanks in advance

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6jqCdBR2fp5EbEv4K3SX?p=preview)

```js
var columnDefs = [{
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Price1",
    field: "price1"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Price2",
    field: "price2"
  }
];

var totalRow = {
  name: "Total",
  price1: 6000,
  price2: 139000
};

var rowData = [{
    name: "Toyota",
    price1: 1000,
    price2: 35000
  },
  {
    name: "Ford",
    price1: 2000,
    price2: 32000
  },
  {
    name: "Porsche",
    price1: 3000,
    price2: 72000
  }
];

var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData,
  floatingBottomRowData: [totalRow]
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

  new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"></script>
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/DyImEnPEQ9MRsWlUxYZM/) to demonstrate the following in action:

```
function addRows (){
  gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(0, rowData);
  var rows = gridOptions.api.getModel().rowsToDisplay
  if (rows.length > 21){
    gridOptions.api.removeItems(rows.slice(-1));
    gridOptions.api.setFloatingBottomRowData([totalRow]);
  }
}

function removeRows(){
    var rowData = [];
    gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function(node) {
        rowData.push(node);
    });
    if (gridOptions.api.getFloatingBottomRowCount()){
      gridOptions.api.removeItems(rowData.slice(-3))
      if (rowData.length < 23){
        gridOptions.api.setFloatingBottomRowData([]);
        gridOptions.api.addItems([totalRow])
      }
    } else {
      gridOptions.api.removeItems(rowData.slice(-4,-1))
    }
}
```

Basically you will need to use the following functions (which are all from the `gridOptions.api`) in your own implementation:

- `removeItems(<rowNodes>[])` - input is an array of rowNodes, best to get these from `getModel()` and filter out the ones you don't want to remove
- `setFloatingBottomRowData(<rowData>[])` - input is an array of object with the same setup that you have in your rowData
- `addItems(<rowNodes>[])`
- `insertItemsAtIndex(insertIndex, <rowData>[])`

More information on these functions can be found on the [Insert & Remove](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) and [Floating Row](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) sections of the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php#gsc.tab=0).

---

As a side note, I can see this as being useful if you are getting the data from a server, in which case you might want to put the logic of checking the number of displayed rows in the `onGridReady` or where ever you are adding data into the grid.

Comment: This is helpful. However, in this way, I need to do all the height calculation separately. I want to use the same apis which agGrid uses to calculate the viewport height and rows heights, so that, the calculations will be in sync.

Comment: or you could use a comparison like this `document.querySelector('.ag-body-viewport').clientHeight > document.querySelector('.ag-body-container').clientHeight`. the viewport is what is viewable, the container is the in memory rows